# WP Plugin Running before jQuery

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I'm having problems with jQuery and a plugin, the console error says jQuery is not defined.  What I don't understand is it only fails when I load it to the production server, on my local dev installation it worked perfectly.

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

The plugin code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_footer', 'enqueue_footer_scripts', 9);
add_filter( 'wp', 'enqueue_styles', 11);

function enqueue_footer_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'sjs', plugins_url('/js/sjs.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sjs' );
    echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { $('p').sJS();});</script>"; 
}

function enqueue_styles() {
    wp_register_style('sjcss', plugins_url('/css/sjs.css', __FILE__), false, '2.1');
    wp_enqueue_style('sjcss');
}
```

Comment: You are doing it wrong. use `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Check the code for `functions.php` you posted. Its the proper way to enqueue script.

Comment: Please don't shout that much. Also don't use tags in the body of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because of a fundamental ordering problem.

You're hooking into wp_footer. Then you're registering a script and enqueueing it. Finally, you echo some code.

Here's the problem, the act of enqueueing a script does not cause an echo of the script code immediately. Enqueueing does just what it says, it sets the script up to be added to the page output at a later time. So your echo of the script code here is too early.

Specifically, the enqueued scripts for the footer happen in the wp_print_footer_scripts call, which is connected to the wp_footer action with priority 20. So you need to enqueue before then, but print your custom script code after then.

So make a new function. Hook it to the wp_print_footer_scripts action. Then move your echo code into that, but leave the enqueue code where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the Codex [this is how to load a script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery):

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'social-highlighter-js', plugins_url('/js/social-highlighter.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Then print your custom initialization scripts in the footer:

```
add_filter( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'my_wp_print_footer_scripts' );

function my_wp_print_footer_scripts() {
    echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { $('p').socialHighlighterShare();});</script>";  
}
```